# Sending Ajax request but not able to receive at the receiver's end

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I am using XMLHTTPRequest object to send some data from one of the templates in Django to another function in view.py

This is a part of my template:

function fun_submit()
{

```
     var var_theme = document.getElementById("theme").value;
        var var_author = document.getElementById("author").value;
        var var_entry = document.getElementById("entry").value;
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlhttp.open('GET',"http://127.0.0.1:8000/first_page/something/",true);
        var data_upload = var_theme;
        xmlhttp.send('w='+encodeURI(var_theme));
        window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/first_page/something/';
        xmlhttp.close();
```

}

and my view function is:

```
def something(request):
        py_data = request.GET.get('w')
        return HttpResponse(py_data)
```

when I return py_data, the page says None. I suspect the data is not getting transmitted. 
I don't want to implement AJAX using JQuery. 
Any help or suggestion is really welcome. Thanks.

Comment: what output this gives 'console.log(encodeURI(var_theme));'

Comment: @VanPeer var data_upload = var_theme;
        xmlhttp.send('w='+encodeURI(var_theme));
        console.log("lets check this::"+encodeURI(var_theme));
        window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/first_page/something/';       I added this line but still cant see anything on the console. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Checked the console?

Comment: @VanPeer yeah no output for that line: Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
October 08, 2017 - 20:50:04
Django version 1.10.6, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[08/Oct/2017 20:50:08] "GET /first_page/welcome/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1527
[08/Oct/2017 20:50:12] "GET /first_page/something/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4
[08/Oct/2017 20:50:12] "GET /first_page/something/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4

Comment: 'console.log(encodeURI("vanpeer"));'

Comment: @VanPeer nothing, I am sorry if this is irritating but even after introducing the line, I see nothing on the console.

Comment: You can try adding the parameter to the URL ``xmlhttp.open('GET', "http://127.0.0.1:8000/first_page/something/?w=" + encodeURI(var_theme), true);``

Comment: @Ivan I tried the same but still getting None at the receiver's end